# "While My App installing Using QR code of Device Owner app, it says Blocked by Play Protect"

Tags: android, kotlin, mdm, device-admin, device-owner

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aikbt.jpg)

I have created a device owner app but I am having trouble installing it on a real device. I'm generating Qr Code Using
https://datalogic.github.io/aeqrdoc/generat.

The text I am using to create my QR Code is

```
{
  "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME": "com.example.demo/com.example.demo.DemoAppDeviceAdminReceiver",
  "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM": "DyseoYKEDCtnYx3jyiHCdLUvZ7F-uFenEe4sZ9bRZYw",
  "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION": "https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/q6094argfv56z8zd1i589/app-release.apk?rlkey=alt5estnbfj5oqazbrmfm7ppc&dl=1"
}
```

I generate my apk from Android studio by doing this:
Build -> Generate Signed Bundle/Apk->select APK-> Create a new keystore -> Ok -> Next-> Select "Release"-> Build. Then I create the package checksum using

```
cat /mnt/c/Users/Antarpuneet/app-release.apk | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 | openssl base64 | tr '+/' '-_' | tr -d '='
```

After doing a factory reset, tapping 6 times on the welcome screen opens a QR reader app, I scan the code and then It takes me to the WIFI connection screen, I successfully connect to the Internet. It says Setting up device.. but returns with the Error Can't setup device- Couldn't install the admin app.

This is DemoAppDeviceAdminReceiver Class :-

```
package com.example.demo;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

import android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DemoAppDeviceAdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
    // Optional: Override methods as needed for handling device admin events
    // For example:
    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Device admin enabled
        super.onEnabled(context, intent);
        Log.d(TAG, "Device Owner Enabled");
        Toast.makeText(context, "DemoAppDeviceAdminReceiver: Enable Device Admin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Return a message when a user tries to disable the device admin
        return "Disabling this device admin will remove important functionality.";
    }

    // Other overrides for admin events as required

    static ComponentName getComponentName(Context context){
        return new ComponentName(context.getApplicationContext(), DemoAppDeviceAdminReceiver.class);
    }


}
```

My Main Activity:-

```
package com.example.demo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int YOUR_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ComponentName adminComponentName = new ComponentName(this, DemoAppDeviceAdminReceiver.class);

        DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

            //TODO: To request Device Admin Activation
            Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, adminComponentName);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Explanation of why your app      needs device admin access");
            //TODO: To start Activity that will prompt the user to grant device Admin privileges to the app
            startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE);

        //TODO: To check the app is device admin or not
        boolean isAdminActive = devicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(adminComponentName);

        if (isAdminActive) {
            // Your app is a device admin
            Toast.makeText(this, "Your app is a device admin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            // Your app is not a device admin
            Toast.makeText(this, "Your app is not a device admin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //TODO: To check the app is device Owner or not
        if (devicePolicyManager.isDeviceOwnerApp("com.example.demo")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i("Status", "Yes");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i("Status", "No");
        }

      //  devicePolicyManager.reboot(adminComponentName);

    }

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swnkZ.jpg)    //TODO: To handle the result of the device Admin Activation request
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == YOUR_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Device admin was activated successfully
                Toast.makeText(this, "Device admin was activated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // Device admin activation was canceled or failed
                Toast.makeText(this, "Device admin activation was canceled or failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }


}
```

My Manifest file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.demo">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Demo"
        android:testOnly="false"
        >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
           >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Declare the Device Admin Receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".DemoAppDeviceAdminReceiver"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"
          >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin_receiver" />
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

device_admin_receive.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin>
    <uses-policies>
        <!-- Define device admin policies here -->
        <limit-password />
        <watch-login />
        <!-- Add other policies your app requires -->
        <reset-password />
        <force-lock />
        <wipe-data />
        <expire-password />
        <encrypted-storage />
        <disable-camera />
        <disable-keyguard-features />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

What I have already tried:

Installing the app on an Emulator using the adb shell command
adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.example.demo/.DemoAppDeviceAdminReceiver

It successfully sets the app as a Device owner.

Installing the app on a real device(after factory reset and skipping sign in page) using the adb command above. It successfully sets up the app as device owner. I think this means that the problem is with the QR-Code.

I am trying to install it on a device with Android Version 13.

Now, My app is being downloaded but while installing, it says Blocked by Play Protect and when I tap on Install Anyway, it returns with the old error: Can't set up device - Couldn't install the admin app

Answer (score 0):

Might be that you have "Verify apps over USB" turned on.

This "Check apps installed via ADB/ADT for harmful behaviour", basic it sends your app to google for review even if you don't ever submit it to Google yourself.

This can be turned of in the Developer system settings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Andrew . after installing using ADB, I reset factory device for installing (using QR Code Scan , this is problem ).

Comment: I turned off "Verify apps over USB" and reset factory But  Blocked by Play Protect with the QR-Code